# Can't find Bitlocker on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I was told that Windows 10 should have Bitlocker available to be enabled but it is not. Did the free version of Win 10 not include this?  I need encryption in order to use the Mail app for my work exchange email.

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be this could help http://superuser.com/questions/942969/can-i-upgrade-to-windows-10-with-bitlocker-enabled

Comment: There is no "free" version of Windows.  The upgrade is only "free" to eligible owners of previous versions of Windows.  There is no different between the a user who pays for the upgrade and a user who accepts the "free" upgrade.  Do you have Home or Professional?  Bitlocker has little to do email encryption though

Comment: My apologies... but my employer won't let me use Mail unless I have encryption.  I see below that it's the edition of Windows (home vs pro) that determine whether you get encryption.  Thanks for answering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BitLocker is only available in [Pro and Enterprise editions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/Compare) of Windows 10, if you've got Windows 10 Home then that feature won't be available to you.

There is a nice explanation of what edition of Windows 10 you will have after your free upgrade on [the Microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq), but I'll do my best to replicate it here:

**Windows 7**

- Starter, Home Basic and Home Premium upgrade to **Windows 10 Home**
- Professional and Ultimate upgrade to **Windows 10 Pro**

**Windows 8**

- The regular edition upgrades to **Windows 10 Home**
- Pro and Pro for Students upgrades to **Windows 10 Pro**

Comment: I feel its worth noting that on Windows 10 you can mount Bitlocker encrypted drives.  Windows 10 just doesn't support encrypting the system drive.  Bitlocker also is a separate feature then "Device Encryption" which Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 tablets support.